# TYPO3 TCA l10n_mode exclude and MM relations

Tags: typo3, translation, extbase, typo3-10.x

in TYPO3 v10.4.9 when I use the following tx_csdummy_domain_model_product.php TCA

```
'items' => [
        'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_csdummy_domain_model_item',
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND (tx_csdummy_domain_model_item.sys_language_uid IN (0,-1)) ORDER BY title ASC',
            'MM' => 'tx_csdummy_product_item_mm',
            ]
        ],
        
    ],
```

and in the tx_csdummy_domain_model_item.php TCA

```
'products' => [
        'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_csdummy_domain_model_product',
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND (tx_csdummy_domain_model_product.sys_language_uid IN (0,-1)) ORDER BY title ASC',
            'MM' => 'tx_csdummy_product_item_mm',
            'MM_opposite_field' => 'items',
            ]
        ],  
    ],
```

it works in the default language as it should. But when I have both sites translated, something goes wrong.

For example I have porduct default (uid=1), product translated (uid=2), item default (uid=5) and item translated (uid=6).

A) If I save the product, then the uid of the translated product points to the default language uid of the item.

```
tx_csdummy_product_item_mm
uid_local  uid_foreign
1          5
2          5
```

B) If I save the item, then the uid of the translated item points to the default language uid of the product.

```
tx_csdummy_product_item_mm
uid_local  uid_foreign
1          5
1          6
```

With A I can't see the related product in the english version of the item in frontend.
With B I can't see the related item in the english version of the product.

Comment: I think this may be a known bug in TYPO3 - see https://forge.typo3.org/issues/88784

Comment: How did you solve it? In my eyes, the whole localization stuff is broker regarding relations, of the backend itself as well as in conjunction with extbase

Comment: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/92777